# Raspberry Pi: commands and tools to get system info

Tags: bash, command-line, raspberry-pi, system-information

I want to write a script to monitor my Raspberry Pi server.  I have found commands like `$ vcgencmd measure_temp` and `$ free -o -h`.  Are there others that would be useful? (I'm especially interested in characteristics that would lead to performance problems.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be much better be asked within the [Raspberry Pi community](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/), or in the very least on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com)? Because as-is, this question is highly Raspberry-specific and not really programming related...

Comment: You're right.  I moved it to the Linux/Unix site, since it's a Linux question, and asked for this to be closed.